# Docker - check private registry image version

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-registry

What CLI commands do I need to use in order to check if the image in my [private docker registry](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/registry/) is a newer version than the one currently running on my server?

E.g. I have a container that I ran using `docker run -d my.domain.com:5000/project1`

and I would like to know if it is out-of-date.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Brownie points to @mbarthelemy and @amuino who put me on track. From that I was able to come up with the following bash script that others may find useful. It just checks if the tag on the registry is different from the currently executing container.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ensure running bash
if ! [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ];then
    echo "this is not bash, calling self with bash....";
    SCRIPT=$(readlink -f "$0")
    /bin/bash $SCRIPT
    exit;
fi


REGISTRY="my.registry.com:5000"
REPOSITORY="awesome-project-of-awesomeness"


LATEST="`wget -qO- http://$REGISTRY/v1/repositories/$REPOSITORY/tags`"
LATEST=`echo $LATEST | sed "s/{//g" | sed "s/}//g" | sed "s/\"//g" | cut -d ' ' -f2`

RUNNING=`docker inspect "$REGISTRY/$REPOSITORY" | grep Id | sed "s/\"//g" | sed "s/,//g" |  tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f3`

if [ "$RUNNING" == "$LATEST" ];then
    echo "same, do nothing"
else
    echo "update!"
    echo "$RUNNING != $LATEST"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Even when there is no command, you can use the API to check for tags on the registry and compare against what you are running.

```
$ curl --silent my.domain.com:5000/v1/repositories//project1/tags | grep latest
{"latest": "116f283e4f19716a07bbf48a562588d58ec107fe6e9af979a5b1ceac299c4370"}

$ docker images --no-trunc my.domain.com:5000/project1
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID                                                           CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
my.domain.com:5000   latest              64d935ffade6ed1cca3de1b484549d4d278a5ca62b31165e36e72c3e6ab8a30f   4 days ago          583.2 MB
```

By comparing the ids, you can know that you are not running the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the `version` but if you mean the `tag` of image, it can be easily checked through the [registry v2 api](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#detail) . Note that in context of docker images **tag has nothing to do with the version of software**.

Use curl command in CLI

```
 curl <docker_host_ip>:<docker_host_port>/v2/<repository_name>/tags/list
```

To get a list of repositories pushed on the private registry, use

```
curl <docker_host_ip>:<docker_host_port>/v2/_catalog
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is not possible right now.

The only thing I see would be to pull the registry to check if there is a new version of your image (would then have a different ID than your locally stored image):

```
docker pull your/image:tag
```

But yes, that would mean fetching the new images (if any).

If you have a look at [the registry API documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/registry_api/#tags), you'll see that if you don't mind scripting a bit, you could get this information without actually downloading the image, by fetching the image tags and check if the returned ID for the tag matches the ID of the local image you have with the same tag.

That being said, having something to "check for updates" integrated into the `docker` CLI would be a nice addition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works as advertised. Just a quick hack I just put together.
But this will at least give you a little push on how this might be done.

```
#!/bin/bash

container=$1
imageid=$(docker inspect --format '{{.Config.Image}}' ${container})

echo "Running version from: $(docker inspect --format '{{.Created}}' ${container})"
echo "Image version from: $(docker inspect --format '{{.Created}}' ${imageid})"
```

Example output:

```
[root@server ~]# sh version_check.sh 9e500019b9d4
Running version from: 2014-05-30T08:24:08.761178656Z
Image version from: 2014-05-01T16:48:24.163628504Z
```

Comment: I am guessing this would work if I was building the image on the same server as is being deployed on, but I'm not, hence the use of the private registry. I can't seem to find any commands for interfacing with the private registry to list images/get info etc.

Comment: Unfortunately (and I cannot figure out the reasons behind that) there is very little interaction with the registry from the `docker` CLI. `docker search`(works with the Index/Hub, not the registry), `docker pull`, `docker tag`, `docker push` and that's pretty much all. I'd really love to have additional commands such as  `docker lr` (list your repos), and `docker check-updates the/repo` (compares local images with repo images versions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bash script running in a `cron` scheduled task:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

docker_instance='YOUR_RUNNING_INSTANCE'

instance_id=$(docker ps -qa --filter name=$docker_instance)
image_name_tag=$(docker inspect $instance_id | jq -r [] |.Config.Image')

if [ "-${image_name_tag}-" != "--" ]; then

    status=$(docker pull $image_name_tag | grep "Downloaded newer image")
    if [ "-${status}-" != "--" ]; then

        echo ">>> There is one update for this image ... "

        # stop the docker instance
        docker stop $docker_instance

        # remove the docker instance
        docker rm $docker_instance

        # restart the docker using the last command, using the new image from the remote repository
        run-my-docker-instance.sh

    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

An older question, but this sounds like a problem that [Watchtower](https://hub.docker.com/r/v2tec/watchtower/) can solve for you.  It is another dockerized application that runs adjacent to your other containers and periodically check to see if their base images are updated.  When they are, it downloads the new image and restarts them.

If given the correct credentials, it can work with a local registry.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I solved it with the bash script below for a while until I decided that [Watchtower](https://hub.docker.com/r/containrrr/watchtower/) was the easier way to go (by the way: note the maintainer switched from `v2tec` to `containrrr` a while ago, the `v2tec` one isn't getting updates anymore). Watchtower gave me an easy way to schedule things without having to rely on `cron` (which gets blown away in a reinstall - granted, you could have something like Ansible recreate that for you, but this was easier for me). It also adds easy notifications (I like using Telegram) for updates, which I appreciate knowing about so that if something goes sideways at  least I know there was an update that could be to blame.

I'm not saying this is will never cause issues, but I've been running Watchtower on various Docker hosts (3 of them, 2 in my homelab, one on Linode) for about a year now and I have yet to have an issue with it. I prefer this to having to manually update my containers on a regular basis. For me the risk of something getting screwed up is lower than the risks of running outdated containers, so this is what I chose for myself. YMMV.

I honestly don't get the apparent hate for automated update solutions like Watchtower - I see so many comments saying that you shouldn't use automated updates because they'll cause problems... I don't know what folks have been burned by - would love to hear more about where this caused problems for you! I mean that, I genuinely don't understand and would love to learn more. I keep having some vague unease about doing automated updates, but given my experience so far I can honestly only recommend it. I used to use [Diun](https://crazymax.dev/diun/) for getting notified about updates and then would go and manually update my containers. That got real old after it became a daily chore! (With ~45 different containers running, you can pretty much guarantee that at least one of them will have an update every single day.)

If I really need to keep a container from updating, I can always stick a `com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=false` label on the container. Or you can whitelist only the containers you want automatically updated, or... There are loads of possibilities with Watchtower.

However, for reference if you still want to use it, see my script below. I used `docker-compose pull` to get the latest version - it does a check first to see if there is a new image, so doesn't waste a whole lot of bandwidth if there is nothing to update. It's effectively like doing the `curl` you guys used. Also I prefer the `docker inspect -f` commands to check the versions to the solutions that pipe through `grep`, `sed`, and co. since that is less likely to get broken by changes to `docker inspect` output format.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /directory/with/docker-compose.yml/
image_name=your-awesome-image
docker-compose pull
container_version=$(docker inspect -f '{{ index .Config.Labels "org.opencontainers.image.version" }}' "$image_name")
latest_image_version=$(docker inspect -f '{{ index .Config.Labels "org.opencontainers.image.version" }}' "$image_name")
if [[ "$container_version" != "$latest_image_version" ]]; then
  echo "Upgrading ${image_name} from ${container_version} to ${latest_image_version}"
  docker-compose down
  docker-compose up -d
fi
```