# Get latest Docker image creation date from registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

How is it possible to get latest creation date of Docker image that exists at registry? Recently we have a problem that Docker image was not automatically pulled at some of our cluster slave servers and the project was running at the very outdated container environment. So am expecting to run a cron-script once per day to check that pulled Docker image is not 24 hours older than registry Docker image.

Comment: Why not just always try to pull? In that case, if the image locally is already as new as the one on your Docker registry, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way I know of is to write a simple script that uses the [Docker Registry REST API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) and does basic manipulation of the results for your needs.

Here's some example code in Python 3 that would do this for a repo I work with:

```
import requests

repo_tag_url = 'https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/streamsets/datacollector/tags'
results = requests.get(repo_tag_url).json()['results']
for repo in results:
    print(repo['name'], repo['last_updated'])
```

Which, for my example, returns:

```
3.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT 2017-10-23T14:43:29.888877Z
latest 2017-10-05T23:05:03.636155Z
2.7.2.0 2017-10-05T22:50:53.269831Z
2.7.2.0-RC5 2017-10-05T19:34:19.523402Z
2.7.2.0-RC4 2017-10-05T02:05:52.522323Z
2.7.2.0-RC3 2017-10-04T00:08:02.929502Z
2.8.0.0-SNAPSHOT 2017-10-03T21:55:08.042479Z
2.7.2.0-RC2 2017-10-03T19:20:56.642686Z
2.7.2.0-RC21 2017-09-30T21:42:27.924190Z
2.7.2.0-RC1 2017-09-30T17:34:14.409320Z
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be what am looking for.

Comment: Maybe this answer is out of date but that doesn't work for me and that endpoint doesn't seem to exist in the API documentation you linked to.  I can hit 'https://server/v2/<name of image>/tags/list' ok but it doesn't give me a create date.

Answer (score 3):

Something like [Docker history](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/#description)?

From the doc:

> Description: Show the history of an image
>
> Usage: docker history [OPTIONS] IMAGE

For example:

```
 $ docker history imageName
```

And using the --format option:

```
$ docker images --format "{{.ID}}: {{.Created}} ago"

cc1b61406712: 2 weeks ago
<missing>: 2 weeks ago
<missing>: 2 weeks ago
<missing>: 2 weeks ago
<missing>: 2 weeks ago
<missing>: 3 weeks ago
<missing>: 3 weeks ago
<missing>: 3 weeks ago
```

Comment: `docker history` shows information about the layers within an image; the question is asking about checking the creation date of a given image on a registry.

Comment: May [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409846/docker-check-private-registry-image-version) can help you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. `docker history` is useful, but not to for what the question's creator is looking to do.

Comment: Also a useful feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below python3 code and Docker registry REST API worked for me.

```
import requests
import json

image_tags = requests.get('http://my-private-registry.example.com:5000/v2/myrepo/tags/list')
latest = []
for tag in image_tags.json()['tags']:
    url = requests.get('http://my-private-registry.example.com:5000/v2/myrepo/manifests/'+tag)
    latest.append((tag, json.loads(url.json()['history'][0]['v1Compatibility']).get('created')))

# sort the list based upon created timestamp stored as the second element of the tuple
latest.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

# return latest image tag from tuple
latest_image = latest[-1][0]
```