# Private Registry automatic download

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Let say I have Docker Private Registry created

```
# docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always -v $HOME/registry:/var/lib/registry registry:2
```

and I am using it to supply the image `vulnerables/web-dvwa` locally.

Is there a way for this private registry to automatically detect and download if there is newer version of the `vulnerables/web-dvwa` image?

In other words check on Docker Hub and comparing with the version in my repository, then update the repository from it?

Comment: I'm not aware of software that does this automatically, but it might be scriptable using techniques similar to those on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409846/docker-check-private-registry-image-version) -- except comparing the latest tag from the local repository and DockerHub, instead of the currently running container.

Comment: @robsiemb [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/v2tec/watchtower/)
is enough for me
but I don't know how to mark your comment as ANSWERED

Comment: Its not really a complete answer though.  You should post what you did (with code) as an answer and then accept that answer.